# Django databrowse with custom queryset?

Tags: django, django-admin

Django's databrowse is very different from the rest of django in that the docs literally don't exist. Has anyone tried to do more that databrowse.site.register on a model? Any code examples?

In particular, I've got a model that has a ForeignKey to an auth.Group and I want databrowse to use this queryset instead of .all():

```
qs = Model.objects.filter(group__in=request.user.groups.all())
```

Bonus points for making it possible to have a button that does stuff with the current object (edit/delete/clone/etc). I basically need a simple way to browse and edit rows without giving users access to the admin.

It'd be even better if there was a way to do that on the admin, but I don't want to give users the staff privilege.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this through databrowse.  You could try writing a [custom Manager](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/managers/)  for your Model and return the required query set by default.