# As Django databrowse is deprecated in django 1.4, is there a better way for databrowsing?

Tags: python, django, admin

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840604/django-databrowse-with-custom-queryset), I know that django.contrib.databrowse is unable to set custom queryset (like filter in django.admin). But I think the way of databrowse to inspect the model and to create the inline table automatically is awesome (In django.admin, I'll have to write my own TabularInline class for each model manually, which is quite suffering).

My question is: as django databrowse is deprecated in django 1.4, is there a better way(for example, another databrowse library) to do the same task?

And is it recommended to use `django admin` or `django databrowse` to make the web interface for users to browse the data?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the same app that somebody else adopted it since its deprecation from django:
https://github.com/Alir3z4/django-databrowse

It's available on pypi too;)